# Simple value assignment from input box returns NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I just assigned the values of the input boxes to variables and now when I want to see the value of the variable from the input box it just shows me, Nan.

```js
var cardamnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cardam").value);
var cashamnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("casham").value);
var giftamnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("giftcheck").value);
var amnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amounttxt").value);

document.getElementById("casham").onchange = function() {
  alert(cashamnt);
};
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1>Payment Details</h1>

  <h3>Amount</h3>
  <input type="text" id="amounttxt">

  <h3>Payment Type</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashbtn">
  <label for="cash">Cash</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cardbtn">
  <label for="card">Card</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashwcardbtn">
  <label for="cashwcard">Cash and Card</label></body><br>

  <h3>Gift Check</h3>
  <input type="text" id="giftcheck">

  <h3>Cash Amount</h3>
  <input type="text" id="casham">

  <h3>Card Amount</h3>
  <input type="text" id="cardam"></br>

  <button id="sumbitbtn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you realize you are reading the values when the page is rendered? Hence your problem.

Comment: Move those `var` inside the event handler...

Comment: `cashamnt` is a primitive, it doesn't refer to the current value of the input. You've to read the value in the change handler.

Comment: Your variable is not in the onchange event. JavaScript is reading the value of the input before the onchage event is fired. So empty input is NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the declaration and push it into `onChange`, You are reading the value when the JS is execting.

```
  var cashamnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("casham").value);
```

Move this line inside `onChange` and it will work as expected.

```js
var cardamnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cardam").value);
var giftamnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("giftcheck").value);
var amnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("amounttxt").value);

document.getElementById("casham").onchange = function() {
  var cashamnt = parseFloat(document.getElementById("casham").value);
  alert(cashamnt);
};
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <h1>Payment Details</h1>

  <h3>Amount</h3>
  <input type="text" id="amounttxt">

  <h3>Payment Type</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashbtn">
  <label for="cash">Cash</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cardbtn">
  <label for="card">Card</label><br>

  <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashwcardbtn">
  <label for="cashwcard">Cash and Card</label></body><br>

  <h3>Gift Check</h3>
  <input type="text" id="giftcheck">

  <h3>Cash Amount</h3>
  <input type="text" id="casham">

  <h3>Card Amount</h3>
  <input type="text" id="cardam"></br>

  <button id="sumbitbtn">Submit</button>
</div>
```